# Canadian Visa stamped

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, indian-citizens

I've an opportunity to work at canada. but i've an issue.  i pursued my MBA in UK.
and was working there. i overstayed there, that's because i was waiting for my extension, did n't receive my docs for very long time then i approached the UK Consulate with copies of my documents and evidence i had. The reply was a shocker that they've lost/find my application and they asked me to communicate through a solicitor. i did that too... it was just a time consumption. so i went to Indian embassy. took a travel document and now i'm back in india. While leaving my passport was not stamped with any overstay but a particular officer wrote a kind of ref. no on my passport. it was 3 years back.

Now i got a job in Canada. 
Will there be any problem in getting the visa or what will happen if i apply?

Comment: The best way to find out will be to apply and see what happens.  This is a question for [Expatriates.se], however.

Comment: @phoog not sure that is good advice; if you make an application and it gets refused, it can make your situation worse.  Better to find out the best way to handle this first.

Comment: @dan1111 you are right.  I commented over-hastily.

Answer (score 3):

you will have to be very careful while applying for Canadian work visa with the following information given :

1 Firstly you said you overstayed in UK and returned in India with a travel document, which means you returned to India without an entry stamp on your passport.
Canadian embassy in India definitely be looking for a last entry stamp on your passport and you must have to declare that in your application  along with your travel document with a valid reason why you choose to come back on a travel document.

2 Secondly the embassy can also find out about your written reference number on your passport from UKBA because UK,USA,CANADA,AUSTRALIA and NEW ZEALAND have strong immigration link together. In this way you cannot conceal your last exit from UK.

3 In canadian visa form page 1 personal details:
  8  previous country of residence during the past  years country.status,from-to

you must have to declare how long you have lived in the past 5 years.

you will have to state everything in your work visa application and have a valid reason for your last overstay in UK.
Also make sure not to conceal or submit any false information otherwise automatically it could be a five year ban for providing any false or misleading information.

i can suggest you consult your case to an established Canadian immigration lawyer/practcioner  before submitting your application

Comment: Why would the Canadian embassy in India care whether an Indian citizen has an Indian entry stamp in his passport?

Comment: applicant will have make sure provide all the necessary information,as i said he needs to mention in personal details about his last stay in uk with specific dates and embassy would be looking for it

Comment: If the applicant follows your advice of presenting everything truthfully (which he of course should), then the applicant would explain the documents he used to return to India, and I find it hard to imagine that this would cause any problems for the application additional to or independent of any problems related to the UK overstay itself.